# Getting the <Link> react router component to compute urls relative to root domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

On goodsite.com, users are presented with a link via react router...The link looks like this

```js
<TableCell    
  component={Link} 
  to={`happy/${thing.id}`} 
 >
 {thing.name}
</TableCell>
```

This link lives on a page at goodsite.com/unhappy.

Under this construction, when users click on the link, they are taken to

goodsite.com/unhappy/happy/dynamicallygenedthing

How could one change the react-router construction above to make sure that users ended up at the following url

goodsite.com/happy/dynamicallygenedthing

Trying to add a forward slash in front of happy

to={`**/**happy/${thing.id}`}

does not seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, getting relative urls via react router's Link component is easy. The following path

```js
<TableCell    
  component={Link} 
  to={`../happy/${thing.id}`} 
 >
 {thing.name}
</TableCell>
```

Worked to output the desired url

goodsite.com/happy/dynamicallygenedthing